# sencha touch 2.. accessing config values while creating views

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have created a view like this

```
Ext.define('App.view.Message', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.message',
    config: {
        layout: 'vbox',
        bigText: 'big Text',
        smallText: 'small text',
        imageUrl: 'imageurl',
        oT: '',
        description: 'message description',

        items: [
            {
            flex: 3,
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 1,
                    items: [
                        {
                            html: '<h3>' + this.getBigText() + '</h3>'
                        },
                        {
                            html: '<h5>' + this.getSmallText() + '</h5>'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'image',
                    src: this.getImageUrl(),
                    flex: 1
                }
            ]
        },
            {
            flex: 6,
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [
                {
                    flex:1,
                    html: '<h3>' + this.getBigText() + '</h3>'
                },
                {
                    flex:5,
                    html: '<p>'+this.getDescription()+'</p>'
                }
            ]
        },
            {
            flex: 1,
            xtype: 'button',
            text: this.getOT()
        }
        ]
    }
})
```

i need to access values that will be passed when this view is created (config values) while creating the view.
so statement `this.getDescription()`, `this.getBigText()` etc etc are generating errors..
what i want is tht the view should be rendered with the config values that i pass is when im creating the view..
what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are define and load a "View" file - browser go through each line. The "View" instance isn't created at that time. So, naturally the **this** cannot be found there.

However, you can use "this" inside the **initialize** function. So, you can write your code like this:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Message', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'message',
    config: {
        layout: 'vbox',
        bigText: 'big Text',
        smallText: 'small text',
        imageUrl: 'imageurl',
        oT: '',
        description: 'message description'
    },

initialize : function(){
     this.add([
            {
            flex: 3,
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 1,
                    items: [
                        {
                            html: '<h3>' + this.bigText + '</h3>'
                        },
                        {
                            html: '<h5>' + this.smallText + '</h5>'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'image',
                    src: this.imageUrl,
                    flex: 1
                }
            ]
        },
            {
            flex: 6,
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [
                {
                    flex:1,
                    html: '<h3>' + this.bigText + '</h3>'
                },
                {
                    flex:5,
                    html: '<p>'+ this.description +'</p>'
                }
            ]
        },
            {
            flex: 1,
            xtype: 'button',
            text: this.oT
        }
        ]);

        this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have to override the constructor and get the config values:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Message', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.message',

config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    bigText: 'big Text',
    smallText: 'small text',
    imageUrl: 'imageurl',
    oT: '',
    description: 'message description'
},

constructor: function(config)
{
    config.items = [
        {
            flex: 3,
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 1,
                    items: [
                        {
                            html: '<h3>' + config.bigText + '</h3>'
                        },
                        {
                            html: '<h5>' + config.smallText + '</h5>'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'image',
                    src: config.imageUrl,
                    flex: 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            flex: 6,
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [
                {
                    flex:1,
                    html: '<h3>' + config.bigText + '</h3>'
                },
                {
                    flex:5,
                    html: '<p>'+config.description+'</p>'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            flex: 1,
            xtype: 'button',
            text: config.oT
        }
    ];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

Answer (score 2):

Sencha Touch 2 does not automatically generate getters and setters for your config. However, there are 2 ways to do what you need:

- Get & set config values directly through `Ext.getCmp('your_component_id').config.bigText` (similar to other configs)
- Manually create getters & setters for your custom config, for example, you have to define something like this as a config of your view component:

  `getBigText: function(){return this.bigText;}`

  `setBigText: function(value) {this.bigText = value;}`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For that I recommend that you add you items to the view in the initialize function like so :

```
  ...
  config:{
  ...
  },
  initialize: function(){
    var me = this;
    me.callParent();

    var container = Ext.create('Ext.Container',{
      title = this.config.bigText
    });

    me.add(container);
  }
  ...
```

I don't know if there is a best solution but this works.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to do that in initialize() function, eg.

```
this.config.title = 'my title';
this.config.iconCls = 'info';
this.callParent();
```